# syntax to iterate through groups of IDs with conditional labeling

Tags: iteration, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby, labeling

I have a question about the right syntax to iterate through groups of IDs with conditional labeling. I have a data set with 'time' (made to numeric here) ,'id', 'vector lengths' and 'quadrant'.

I wish to iterate through each unique 'ID' and create a column with label (1 = 'interaction') when the unique ID AND at least one of the other IDs in the same time (for example time 2) are above or below a threshold in the column 'vec_len' ( quantile 0.01 and 0.99).

Can anyone help? I tried but i obviously fail get the logic..

Expected output based on the outer and inner quantiles of individual ids. I used 0.5 and -0.5 for illustration. And then a column with the grouping.

```
time   id   vec_len  quadrant   interaction    Paired with

1    3271    0.9    7   0 
1    3229    0.1    0   0
1    4228    0.5    0   0
1    2778   -0.3    5   0
2    4228    0.2    0   0
2    3271    0.1    6   0
2    3229    -0.7   5   1    [2778, 4228]
2    3229    -0.3   2   0
2    4228    -0.8   5   1    [2778, 3229]
2    2778   -0.6    5   1    [4228]
3    4228    0.2    0   0
3    3271    0.1    6   0
3    4228    -0.7   5   1    [3271]
3    3229    -0.3   2   0
3    3271    -0.8   5   1    [4228]
```

Why wouldnt this work for the first part?

```
for g_idx, group in id_group:
     for r_idx, row in group.iterrows():
             if (row['vec_len'] > group.groupby('id') ['vec_len'].quantile(0.75).any()) or row['vec_len'] < group.groupby('id')['vec_len'].quantile(0.25).any():
        df.loc[r_idx, 'intera'] = 1
```

Comment: For better understanding, can you add expected output?

Comment: Here you go, I hope this is understandable. The quadrant column can be ignored for now.